# Algorithm to detect unusual growth/fall in my numbers

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have a dataset with visitor number who visited my site's pages during the last 30 days, it looks something like this:

```
Page 1: [1,2,66,2,2,7,8]
Page 2: [3,5,8,3,7,11,45]
```

The total amount of pages is huge. I would like to apply an algorithm to detect pages which had sudden growth, spikes or downfalls during the period.  Is there a single algorithm that lets me do that?

Comment: I guess you need to be more precise on what you consider an 'unexpected' evolution of page visits. An elementary test would be `Math.abs(x_(t+1)-x_t) > threshold`. Depending on the environment you do the analysis in, you may have access to matrix operations to process many pages simulataneously (from the programmer's perspective, anyway). I'd probably opt for a stats package, though that might be overkill

Answer (score 1):

```
int Q = 20;     //Q should be the difference 
                //between two pages that should be 
                //considered a spike

for (int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    page p = pages[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < p.visitors.length - 1; j++){
        if(p.visitors[j] >= p.visitors[j+1] + Q){
            print("Page " + i + " has spike in day " + j);
        }
        else if(p.visitors[j] + Q <= p.visitors[j+1] + Q){
            print("Page " + i + " has spike in day " + (j+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Z-score](http://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/), so based on the mean and standard deviations you can estimate pikes.

**For example**

In `page 1`:

- Mean: `12.571428571429`
- Std Dv: `23.719592062661`

Z-score(Number of standard deviations from the mean a data point) for values of `page 1`:

- `[-0.4878,-0.44568,2.2525,-0.44568,-0.44568,-0.23489,-0.19273]`

So you can note that the third value is `2.2525` standard deviations from the mean, which is probably a pike(sudden growth, because is positive). The others values seems expected.

Answer (score 1):

Statistically speaking, a value in a data set is considered an outlier when it's distance from `Q1` or `Q3` is larger than `1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)` where `Q1` and `Q3` represent the first and third quartile respectively.

You could implement this with an algorithm that calculates `Q1` and `Q3` based on the last `n` days (e.g. 30) and go from there.

1. Find `Q1` and `Q3`
2. IQR = `1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)`
3. Loop through array
4. Check `page[i] <= Q1 - IQR`. If true: outlier
5. Check `page[i] >= Q3 + IQR`. If true: outlier

So far, so good. However.

### **Finding `Q1` and `Q3` is a bit tricky.**

**You could either A)**

Calculate them the easy way I.E *not technically correct*

1. Find average
2. Divide by 2. This is `Q1`
3. Add `Q1` to average. This is `Q3`

**Or B)**

Find some other way of calculating the quartiles. Visit [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) for reference.